# Does Component triggers OnDestroy when navigating through its own routes?

Tags: angular, angular-router

Let's say I have a FooComponent, and I have the routes below (app.routes.ts),

> If I'm on this route: **/app/foo/arg1** and I want to go to
> **/app/foo/arg1/arg2** does OnDestroy gets called **by default** ?

I've tried to find some information from the official doc https://angular.io/guide/router and from here but couldn't find an explicit answer for that. If you move between the same route such as /app/foo/:arg1 component is reused but when you add a level (/app/foo/:arg1/:arg2) it gets destroyed and I don't know if that's how Angular Route works by default.

Also I've found out that you can override default's RouteStrategy to set your own behave.

Thanks a lot !

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'foo', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { 
        path: 'foo' ,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                component: FooComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':arg1',
                component: FooComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':arg1/:arg2',
                component: FooComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':arg1/:arg2/:arg3',
                component: FooComponent
            },
            {
                path: ':arg1/:arg2/:arg3/:arg4',
                component: FooComponent
            }
        ]
    }
] 
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutes {}
```

Comment: I could provide 2 options for you. 1: use query params (params after ?) 2: use 1 route with complex matcher https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher. The first option is really the easier and  I believe it is better suits your situation from logical point of view

Comment: Hi @Andrei, I'm already using option 1) by adding Resolvers into my routes file and also the option 2) by using path and pathMatch which is equivalent